# Replace numeric character references in XML document using Python

Tags: python, xml

I am struggling with the following issue: I have an XML string  that contains the following tag and I want to convert this, using cElementTree, to a valid XML document:

```
<tag>#55296;#57136;#55296;#57149;#55296;#57139;#55296;#57136;#55296;#57151;#55296;
#57154;#55296;#57136;</tag>
```

but each # sign is preceded by a & sign and hence the output looks like: ��������������

This is a unicode string and the encoding is UTF-8. I want to discard these numeric character references because they are not legal XML in a valid XML document (see [Parser error using Perl XML::DOM module, "reference to invalid character number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223391/parser-error-using-perl-xmldom-module-reference-to-invalid-character-number))

I have tried different regular expression to match these numeric character references. For example, I have tried the following (Python) regex:

```
RE_NUMERIC_CHARACTER = re.compile('&#[\d{1,5}]+;')
```

This does work in regular python session but as soon as I use the same regex in my code then it doesn't work, presumably because those numeric characters have been interpreted (and are shown as boxes or question marks).

I have also tried the unescape function from http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm but that does not work either.

Thus: how can I match, using a regular expression in Python, these numeric character references and create a valid XML document?

Comment: It already is a valid document.  The characters are valid Unicode characters.  The output looks like junk because you're probably not printing in an encoding that your console tolerates.  What OS?  What is the Unicode encoding for your console?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 but I am not using the console at all, the error is thrown when I feed the string to cElementTree.XML()

Comment: @S.Lott: `&#55296;` is not a valid character reference, as it refers to a surrogate code unit (0xD800).

Comment: @DrDee:  "hence the output looks like..." and "the error is thrown when I feed the string"  doesn't make any sense to me.  What **exact** error are you getting?  Please copy and paste.

Comment: @S.Lott: I am reading from a file XML, I am trying to construct XML DOM from this file (using cElementTree), the file contains above mentioned tag and the error message I get is: SyntaxError: reference to invalid character number. Hence, I am trying to strip out those numerical characters but haven't been successful yet. I will use @bobince solution tomorrow

Comment: @DrDee: Please do not put important information in a comment.  Formatting is lost.  Please **update** your question with all of the actual error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eurgh. You've got surrogates (UTF-16 code units in the range D800-DFFF), which some fool has incorrectly encoded individually instead of using a pair of code units for a single character. It would be ideal to replace this mess with what it *should* look like:

```
<tag>&#66352;&#66365;&#66355;&#66352;&#66367;&#66370;&#66352;</tag>
```

Or, just as valid, in literal characters (if you've got a font that can display the Gothic alphabet):

```
<tag></tag>
```

Usually, it would be best to do replacement operations like this on parsed text nodes, to avoid messing up non-character-reference sequences in other places like comments or PIs. However of course that's not possible in this case since this isn't really XML at all. You could try to fix it up with a crude regex, though it would be better to find out where the invalid input is coming from and kick the person responsible until they fix it.

```
>>> def lenient_deccharref(m):
...    return unichr(int(m.group(1)))
...
>>> tag= '<tag>&#55296;&#57136;&#55296;&#57149;&#55296;&#57139;&#55296;&#57136;&#55296;&#57151;&#55296;&#57154;&#55296;&#57136;</tag>'
>>> re.sub('&#(\d+);', lenient_deccharref, tag).encode('utf-8')
'<tag>\xf0\x90\x8c\xb0\xf0\x90\x8c\xbd\xf0\x90\x8c\xb3\xf0\x90\x8c\xb0\xf0\x90\x8c\xbf\xf0\x90\x8d\x82\xf0\x90\x8c\xb0</tag>'
```

This is the correct UTF-8 encoding of . The `utf-8` codec allows you to encode a sequence of surrogates to correct UTF-8 even on a wide-Unicode platform where the surrogates should not have appeared in the string in the first place.

```
>>> _.decode('utf-8')
u'<tag>\U00010330\U0001033d\U00010333\U00010330\U0001033f\U00010342\U00010330</tag>'
```

Comment: OKay, I need to replicate this. The original code does contain the & character but I left it out so it would show on Stackflow.

Comment: I omitted the `&` in the example initially due to a mis-paste, but it does work. If you put `&#...;` in a code block (backticks or four spaces), SO doesn't try to treat it as a character reference.

Comment: -1 on the question as a whole: "The original code does contain the & character".  If you can't post the actual code, it requires a genius to deduce what you did wrong.