# Convert numeric character reference notation to unicode string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Is there a standard, preferably Pythonic, way to convert the `&#xxxx;` notation to a proper unicode string?

For example,

```
&#1502;&#1508;&#1490;&#1513;&#1497;
```

Should be converted to:

```
מפגשי
```

It can be done - quite easily - using string manipulations, but I wonder if there's a standard library for this.

Comment: Hint: that notation is called ["numeric character reference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference).

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894564/replace-numeric-character-references-in-xml-document-using-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663058/html-entity-codes-to-text

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: that one is about a very specific case (UTF-16 codepoints encoded as characters), Jared: that one is about *named* character references (it's possible that the answers still apply, but I don't know).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`HTMLParser.HTMLParser()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html):

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser()
>>> s = "&#1502;&#1508;&#1490;&#1513;&#1497;"
>>> print h.unescape(s)
מפגשי
```

It's part of the [standard library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/), too.

---

However, if you're using Python 3, you have to import from `html.parser`:

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser()
>>> s = '&#1502;&#1508;&#1490;&#1513;&#1497;'
>>> print(h.unescape(s))
מפגשי
```

Comment: `unescape` appears to be internal and undocumented. Is there an "official" way?

Comment: @thg435 Not that I know of, sorry

Comment: I haven't found it either. Well, this kinda sucks, doesn't it?

Comment: Seems there's now an official way since Python 3.4 using [html.unescape(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape).